# Parse a string using regex to obtain matches beginning with a certain word

Tags: python, regex, string

I tried to search but the information that I am getting seems to be kinda overwhelming and far from what I need. I can't seem to get it to work.
The requirement is to get the function that starts with "meta" and its parentheses.

```
input:
one metaOmph(uno)
one metaAsdf(dos)
one metaPoil(tres)

output:
[ metaOmph , (uno) ]
[ metaAsdf,  (dos) ]
[ metaPoil,  (tres)]
```

The one that I currently have just gets the entire line if it starts with "meta". so I have the entire "one meta<>" if it's a match, would it be possible do what I'm aiming for?

Edit: It's one input/line at a time.

I'd love to post what I did earlier but I closed repl.it due to my frustration. I'll keep it in mind on my next post. (quite new here)

Comment: You should add here, what it is you tried. It's obvious you tried something but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

s = """one metaOmph(uno)
one metaAsdf(dos)
one metaPoil(tres)"""

print(re.findall(".+(meta\w+)(\(\w+\))", s))
```

Outputs:

```
[('metaOmph', '(uno)'), ('metaAsdf', '(dos)'), ('metaPoil', '(tres)')]
```

Comment: Thank you! would it be possible to use re.match? The input is one line each btw.. sorry I forgot to state that

Comment: @AndrewNguyen Actually this won't work - for a good reason. If a word ends with meta, it will also be picked up as a false positive.

Comment: I counted your score, thanks for the revenge downvote :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to pass a multiline string, it would seem simple to use the module level `re.findall` function.

```
text = '''one metaOmph(uno)
one metaAsdf(dos)
one metaPoil(tres)'''

r = re.findall(r'\b(meta.*?)(\(.*?\))', text, re.M)
print(r)
[('metaOmph', '(uno)'), ('metaAsdf', '(dos)'), ('metaPoil', '(tres)')]
```

---

If you are going to be passing 1-line strings as input to a loop, it might make more sense to compile the pattern beforehand, using `re.compile` and `re.search` inside a function:

```
pat = re.compile(r'\b(meta.*?)(\(.*?\))')
def find(text):
    return pat.search(text)

for text in list_of_texts: # assuming you're passing in your strings from a list, or elsewhere
    m = find(text)  
    if m:
        print(list(m.groups()))

['metaOmph', '(uno)']
['metaAsdf', '(dos)']
['metaPoil', '(tres)']
```

Note that `m` might return a `match` object *or* `None` depending on whether a search was found. You'll want to query the return value, otherwise you'll receive an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'`, or something along those lines.

Alternatively, if you want to append the result to a list, you might instead use:

```
r_list = []
for text in list_of_texts:
    m = find(text)  
    if m:
        r_list.append(list(m.groups()))

print(r_list)
[['metaOmph', '(uno)'], ['metaAsdf', '(dos)'], ['metaPoil', '(tres)']]
```

---

**Regex Details**

```
\b     # word boundary (thought to add this in thanks to Roman's answer)
(
meta   # literal 'meta'
.*?    # non-greedy matchall
)
(
\(     # literal opening brace (escaped)
.*?
\)     # literal closing brace (escaped) 
)
```

Comment: Hey Coldspeed! Thanks for the breakdown! I'll go ahead and review it

Comment: @AndrewNguyen Yeah, thought you should be able to learn from what you are doing than blindly copy from a half baked answer.

Comment: Noted. I also updated my question to clarify that it's one input at a time. so "one metaOmph(uno)" will be the first input.

Comment: @AndrewNguyen Added some more options for you as well. You asked if `re.match` was possible. I think `re.search` is what you want instead. You can choose to append to a list or print in the loop as is.

Comment: @AndrewNguyen Also note that while you may not be able to up vote till you have 15 rep, you can _accept_ the answer that helped the most.

Answer (score 0):

`re.findall()` approach with valid regex pattern:

```
import re

s = '''
one metaOmph(uno)
one metaAsdf(dos)
one metaPoil(tres)
'''

result = re.findall(r'\b(meta\w+)(\([^()]+\))', s)
print(result)
```

The output:

```
[('metaOmph', '(uno)'), ('metaAsdf', '(dos)'), ('metaPoil', '(tres)')]
```